# Adding a CSS class to drupal_set_message

Tags: php, string, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I'm trying to add a CSS class to a specific message in Drupal that is output upon success when subscribing to a mailchimp list, here's the code for for submission function:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
global $base_url;

$list_details = mailchimp_get_lists($this->signup->mc_lists);

$subscribe_lists = array();

// Filter out blank fields so we don't erase values on the Mailchimp side.
$mergevars = array_filter($form_state->getValue('mergevars'));

$email = $mergevars['EMAIL'];

$mailchimp_lists = $form_state->getValue('mailchimp_lists');

// If we only have one list we won't have checkbox values to investigate.
if (count(array_filter($this->signup->mc_lists)) == 1) {
  $subscribe_lists[0] = array(
    'subscribe' => reset($this->signup->mc_lists),
    'interest_groups' => isset($mailchimp_lists['interest_groups']) ? $mailchimp_lists['interest_groups'] : NULL,
  );
}
else {
  // We can look at the checkbox values now.
  foreach ($mailchimp_lists as $list) {
    if ($list['subscribe']) {
      $subscribe_lists[] = $list;
    }
  }
}

$successes = array();

// Loop through the selected lists and try to subscribe.
foreach ($subscribe_lists as $list_choices) {
  $list_id = $list_choices['subscribe'];

  $interests = isset($list_choices['interest_groups']) ? $list_choices['interest_groups'] : array();
  if (isset($this->signup->settings['safe_interest_groups']) && $this->signup->settings['safe_interest_groups']) {
    $current_status = mailchimp_get_memberinfo($list_id, $email);
    if (isset($current_status->interests)) {
      $current_interests = array();
      foreach ($current_status->interests as $id => $selected) {
        if ($selected) {
          $current_interests[$id] = $id;
        }
      }
      $interests[] = $current_interests;
    }
  }
  $result = mailchimp_subscribe($list_id, $email, $mergevars, $interests, $this->signup->settings['doublein']);

  if (empty($result)) {
    drupal_set_message(t('There was a problem with your newsletter signup to %list.', array(
      '%list' => $list_details[$list_id]->name,
    )), 'warning');
  }
  else {
    $successes[] = $list_details[$list_id]->name;
  }
}

if (count($successes) && strlen($this->signup->settings['confirmation_message'])) {
  drupal_set_message($this->signup->settings['confirmation_message'], 'status');
}

$destination = $this->signup->settings['destination'];
if (empty($destination)) {
  $destination_url = Url::fromRoute('<current>');
}
else {
  $destination_url = Url::fromUri($base_url . '/' . $this->signup->settings['destination']);
}

$form_state->setRedirectUrl($destination_url);
```

}

I'm specifically interested in altering this portion:

```
if (count($successes) && strlen($this->signup->settings['confirmation_message'])) {
  drupal_set_message($this->signup->settings['confirmation_message'], 'status');
}
```

I would like to add a class that is output only for this confirmation message, and not for all of them. I've tried a couple things:

1. According to some related Q&A, I've tried editing the 'status' portion above to add a class there: 'status conf' or 'status, conf', neither of these work, the only accepted values are 'status', 'warning', and 'error', other values are not translated.
2. I've also tried this:

   if (count($successes) && strlen($this->signup->settings['confirmation_message'])) {
   drupal_set_message('' . $this->signup->settings['confirmation_message'] . '', 'status');

This option doesn't add the markup and just outputs it as a string:

```
"<div class="conf">Our confirmation message</div>"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A twig template is used to output the message html.
Why the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/8.5.x) suggests there are only 3 options for the 'type' parameter, I don't know, but it is wrong. The status messages are just like any other themable (is that a word?) output.

Adding your own class, eg. `drupal_set_message('Our confirmation message', 'conf');` does work, except the class (when the classy theme template is used) will be `messages--conf`.

In the case of the 'classy' theme, the template for messages is located at "core/themes/classy/templates/misc/status-messages.html.twig" and it looks like this:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override for status messages.
 *
 * Displays status, error, and warning messages, grouped by type.
 *
 * An invisible heading identifies the messages for assistive technology.
 * Sighted users see a colored box. See http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H69.html
 * for info.
 *
 * Add an ARIA label to the contentinfo area so that assistive technology
 * user agents will better describe this landmark.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - message_list: List of messages to be displayed, grouped by type.
 * - status_headings: List of all status types.
 * - attributes: HTML attributes for the element, including:
 *   - class: HTML classes.
 */
#}
{% block messages %}
{% for type, messages in message_list %}
  {%
    set classes = [
      'messages',
      'messages--' ~ type,
    ]
  %}
  <div role="contentinfo" aria-label="{{ status_headings[type] }}"{{ attributes.addClass(classes)|without('role', 'aria-label') }}>
    {% if type == 'error' %}
      <div role="alert">
    {% endif %}
      {% if status_headings[type] %}
        <h2 class="visually-hidden">{{ status_headings[type] }}</h2>
      {% endif %}
      {% if messages|length > 1 %}
        <ul class="messages__list">
          {% for message in messages %}
            <li class="messages__item">{{ message }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% else %}
        {{ messages|first }}
      {% endif %}
    {% if type == 'error' %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
  {# Remove type specific classes. #}
  {% set attributes = attributes.removeClass(classes) %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock messages %}
```

To override it, just add your own 'status-messages.html.twig' to your theme (MY_THEME/templates/misc/status-messages.html.twig) and alter as needed.